# Rewriting ( set<pair<x,y>> ) as a struct

Tags: c++

I have to write this:

```
set<pair<float,int>>foo;
foo.insert(make_pair(a, b));

while (!foo.empty())
{
    float dist = foo.begin()->first;
    int u = foo.begin()->second;
}
```

But I want to use my own implementation without adding all the functionality of set/pair.

This is basically what I want pair to do:

```
struct pair2
{
    float first;
    int second;

    pair2(float arg_first, int arg_second)
    {
        first = arg_first;
        second = arg_second;
    }

    pair2 make_pair2(float first2, int second2)
    {
        return (pair2(first2,second2));
    }
};
```

I'm not sure if that's completely correct, but I also have to implement set to work with it:

```
set<pair>foo;   //not set<pair<float,int>>foo; since not templated
foo.insert(make_pair2(a,b));
```

What's the best way to do this? Should I implement set using a vector? All I need set to have is:  empty(), begin(), erase() and insert() which vectors already have.

Comment: I'm confused what you're trying to do. Your first code fragment is an infinite loop.

Comment: Wait, why do you not want to use the standard containers?  There is no reason to reinvent the wheel to get rid of some features.

Comment: @erip I'm trying to implement things like empty() with set, using a pair. I know it's an infinite loop, I just wanted to give an example.

Comment: For a set, you'll have to provide a comparison function (such as `bool operator<(const pair2 &, const pair2 &)`), so the set knows how to order your pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to have a pair that is "untemplated". You can type alias, which you can use to rename types to some custom type.

Instead of typing `std::pair<float, int>` each time, you could call it `my_pair`.

This is how you can do it in C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <set>

using my_pair = std::pair<float, int>;

my_pair make_my_pair(float a, int b) {
  return std::make_pair(a, b);
}

int main() {
  my_pair a(1.5, 2);
  my_pair b = make_my_pair(2.2, 3);
  std::cout << a.first << " " << a.second << std::endl;
  std::cout << b.first << " " << b.second << std::endl;

  std::set<my_pair> foo;
  foo.insert(make_my_pair(3.4, 4));

  return 0;
}
```

Be sure to compile with `-std=c++11`.

---

If you can't/don't want to use C++11 constructs, you can do this as well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <set>

typedef std::pair<float, int> my_pair;

my_pair make_my_pair(float a, int b) {
  return std::make_pair(a, b);
}

int main() {
  my_pair a(1.5, 2);
  my_pair b = make_my_pair(2.2, 3);
  std::cout << a.first << " " << a.second << std::endl;
  std::cout << b.first << " " << b.second << std::endl;

  std::set<my_pair> foo;
  foo.insert(make_my_pair(3.4, 4));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The new thing `using` enables is not template aliases, but alias templates. You can very well do `typedef std::pair<float, int> my_pair`, what you can't do is `template <class T> typedef std::pair<float, T> my_pair`.

Comment: `make_my_pair` should also continue to delegate `std::make_pair`, it defaults to forwarding mechanics instead of constructor/destructor calls.

Comment: I was just thinking that before I noticed the comment... edited.